# If $f$ is a solution to a known differential equation, then can you find the differential equation that solves $f^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $f$ is a solution to a second-order differential equation (the specific application here is the Bessel function). Can we find the differential equation that solves $f^2$?

Comment: Hint: change of unknown function.

Comment: If $f'=\phi(t,f)$, then for $g=f^2$ you get $g'=2\sqrt{g}\phi(t,\sqrt{g})$. This obviously works best if $\phi(t,f)$ is odd in $f$.